# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} (\ln (x+e))^{\cot x}$ without l'Hôpital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  (\ln (x+e))^{\cot x}$$

Since we have an indeterminate form of $1^{\infty }$, we should simplify in a way that we can transform the expression into *e* to the power of something, but I can't find a way.

The use of l'Hôpital's rule or series is prohibited.

Comment: You mean like $$(\ln(x+e))^{\cot(x)}=\exp(\cot(x)\ln(\ln(x+e)))$$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde My class can't use l'Hôpital until the next semester, even if we can prove it. So I have to do it the difficult way.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, yes, probably something like this, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: the answer is 1.44 something.. if that help

Comment: @DietrichBurde: yes, the "whole industry" is called "mathematics". L'Hôpital gives no information whatsoever on rate of convergence, so it is at best an incomplete tool. Using Taylor polynomials is usually the same amount of effort,  it does not suffer from "L'Hôpital does not apply" pitfalls, and gives you a good approximation and not just the limit. Also, maybe more importantly, it requires understanding from the student, as opposed to blindly applying machinery.

Comment: @DietrichBurde L'Hospital's rule is fairly overkill for this IMHO.

Comment: The real question is does L'Hopitals rule make the question simpler. Sometimes it does, other times it makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you want to compute the limit of the logarithm of your function:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\cot x\ln(\ln(x+e))
$$
The first step is almost obvious: note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x\cot x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin x}\cos x=1
$$
so you can reduce to computing
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\ln(x+e))}{x}
$$
because if this limit exists it will be equal to the one you want to compute.

How do we do this one? Let's do the substitution $x=et$, so it becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln(\ln e+\ln(1+t))}{et}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\ln(1+t))}{et}
$$
Not yet in the best form. Let's do a new substitution: $\ln(1+t)=u$, that is, $t=e^u-1$, so we get
$$
\frac{1}{e}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{e^u-1}=
\frac{1}{e}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}\frac{u}{e^u-1}=…
$$

> Since $$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=1\qquad\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u}{e^u-1}=1$$ are both known limits, you can conclude that $$\lim_{x\to0}\cot x\ln(\ln(x+e))=\frac{1}{e}$$ Therefore $$\lim_{x\to0}(\ln(x+e))^{\cot x}=e^{1/e}$$

Of course, using l'Hôpital is easier and doesn't require imagination:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\ln(x+e))}{\tan x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\ln(x+e)}\dfrac{1}{x+e}}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{e}
$$

Comment: :P Even more elementary than my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see! We actually do such substitutions, it seems like the answer that is expected by our teacher. I'll try to analyze it and solve the similar problems in this way in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TaisiaSharapova The first substitution $x=et$ is to get $\ln(1+t)$ that's a more familiar expression; the second one is for transforming the complicated $\ln(1+\ln(1+t))$ again into $\ln(1+u)$. It takes practice, but is, in my opinion, a huge waste of time: Taylor expansion is much more powerful as is using derivatives like in another answer.

Comment: @egreg I would love to use Taylor expansion, but our teacher told us that everything on our exam should be solved without it or l'Hopital. I tried to practice by solving the hardest ones without it but had little success and, finally, went to the StackExchange. Thank you again for the detailed explanations!

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite it as
$$(\ln(x+e))^{\cot(x)}=\exp\left[x\cot(x)\frac{\ln(\ln(x+e))}x\right]$$

And use the known limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$$

To get

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\cot(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^{-1}=1\cdot1^{-1}=1$$

and then use the definition of the derivative to compute

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\ln(x+e))}x=\frac d{dx}\ln(\ln(x+e))\bigg|_{x=0}$$

Evaluating the derivative with chain rule and

$$\frac d{dx}\ln(x)=\frac1x$$

which should give you a final result of

$$\lim_{x\to0}(\ln(x+e))^{\cot(x)}=e^{1/e}$$

Comment: Can you ELI5 what is a *derivative with chain rule*? I'm not sure that we are allowed to use that. I got the rest of your explanation though, thank you very much!

Comment: @TaisiaSharapova We have$$\frac d{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$under some conditions, and so$$\frac d{dx}\ln(\ln(x+e))=\frac{d\ln(u)}{du}\frac{d\ln(x+e)}{dx}$$where $u=\ln(x+e)$. This gives us$$\frac1u\frac1{x+e}=\frac1{(x+e)\ln(x+e)}$$To which we finally substitute $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the natural log you have 
$$\cot x \ln \ln(x+e))=$$
$$\cos x \frac{x}{\sin x} \frac{\ln \ln (x+e)}{\ln (x+e)-1}\frac{\ln(x+e)-1}{x}$$
The initial factors all limit to $1$, as for the last,
$$\frac{\ln(x+e)-1}{x}=
\frac{\ln(x+e)-\ln e}{x}=\frac{\ln(\frac{x}{e}+1)}{x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{e}\frac{\ln(\frac{x}{e}+1)}{x/e}\to\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

$$\ln(x+e)=\ln e +\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{e}\right)=1+\frac{x}{e}+o(x)$$

Thus:

> $$(\ln (x+e))^{\cot x}=\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{e}+o(x)\right)^\frac1x\right]^\frac{x}{tanx}\to e^{\frac1e}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
\begin{align}
\ln(e+x)^{\cot x}&=\ln\left(e(1+\frac xe)\right)^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=\left(1+\ln(1+\frac xe)\right)^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}\\ \ \\
&=\left(1+\frac xe+o(x^2) \right)^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}\\ \ \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,\ln\left(1+\frac xe+o(x^2) \right) \right)\\ \ \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,\left(\frac xe+o(x^2)\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1+o(x^2)}{x+o(x^3)}\,\left(\frac xe+o(x^2)\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1+o(x^2)}{1+o(x^2)}\,\left(\frac 1e+o(x)\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\exp\left(\frac1e\right)=e^{1/e}.
\end{align}
The relevant Taylor polynomials used above are 
$$
\ln(1+x)=x+o(x^2),\ \ \cos x=1+o(x^2),\ \ \ \sin x=x+o(x^3),
$$
together with $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ (which is the definition of $a^b$)

Comment: I stated in my question that I can't use series, unfortunately. But thank you for the feedback.

Comment: This is not "series", it's "Taylor polynomials". And you won't be able to do much about limits of logarithms, exponentials, and trigonometric series without them. Anyway, since you are so explicit about what is **not** allowed, you should probably state what **is** allowed.

Comment: Any manipulation that doesn't involve Taylor, l'Hôpital or derivatives is allowed, I believe. For example, "known limits" such as $\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty } (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x = e$ or equivalent infinitesimals.

Comment: @TaisiaSharapova What do you mean by "infinitesimals"?

Comment: I was also not aware that you were prohibiting derivatives too @TaisiaSharapova

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry for taking a long time to answer! By *infinitesimals* I meant [these](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Indeterminate_form#/Equivalent_infinitesimal).

Comment: @Taisia: do you understand that those "infinitesimals" you mention are exactly what I used in my answer? Only that you cannot correctly replace them inside a limit; how would you use that table to correctly calculate the following? $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}.$$